# Имитация взаимного блокирования потоков

Tags: java

Пытаюсь разобраться с потоками, хочу заставить потоки блокировать друг друга.
Я так понимаю потоки должны циклично задействовать или ожидать друг друга, но не понимаю как это реализовать. Вот мой код.

```
packagedeadlock;
class A
{
synchronized  void foo(B b)
     {
         String name=Thread.currentThread().getName();
         System.out.println(name +" вошел а A.foo()");
         try
         {
             Thread.sleep(1000);
         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
             System.out.println("A прерван");
         }
         System.out.println(name+" пытается вызвать B.last()");
         b.last();
     }
     void last()
     {
         System.out.println(" внутри A.last()");
     }
}

class B
{
     synchronized  void bar(A a)
     {
         String name=Thread.currentThread().getName();
         System.out.println(name +" вошел в B.bar()");
         try
         {
             Thread.sleep(1000);
         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
             System.out.println("B прервано");
         }
         System.out.println(name+" пытается вызвать A.last()");
         a.last();
     }
     void last()
     {
         System.out.println(" внутри B.last()");
     }
}
public class Deadlock implements Runnable
{

    A a=new A();
    B b=new B();
    Deadlock()
    {
        Thread.currentThread().setName("MainThread");
        Thread t=new Thread(this, "RacingThread");
        t.start();
        a.foo(b);
        System.out.println("Назад в главный поток");
    }
    public void run()
    {
        b.bar(a);
        System.out.println("Назад в другой поток");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       new Deadlock();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы добиться дедлока нужно:

1. два ресурса
2. два потока
3. чтобы потоки одновременно захватили по одному разному ресурсу
4. чтобы потоки попытались захватить второй ресурс

В этом случае они будут ждать друг друга бесконечно.

Реализовать можно так:

```
public class T {

  static class A {
    private CyclicBarrier barrier;
    A(CyclicBarrier barrier) {
      this.barrier = barrier;
    }
    synchronized void f(A other, boolean nested) throws InterruptedException, BrokenBarrierException {
      // в этой точке монитор объекта this захвачен
      if (!nested) {
        barrier.await(); // ждем пока второй поток дойдет до этой же точки
        other.f(this, true); // пробуем захватить монитор объекта other
      }
    }
  }

  public void lockInOrder(A first, A second) {
    try {
      first.f(second, false);
    } catch (InterruptedException | BrokenBarrierException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }

  @Test
  public void deadlock() throws InterruptedException {
    CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier(2);
    A a1 = new A(barrier);
    A a2 = new A(barrier);

    Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
      lockInOrder(a1, a2);
    });
    Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
      lockInOrder(a2, a1);
    });

    t1.start();
    t2.start();

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
  }
}
```

То, что потоки в дедлоке (т.е. ждут мониторы захваченные друг другом) видно с помощью `jstack`. Обратите внимание на строки с `locked` и `waiting for lock`:

```
"Thread-2" #21 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fe8758f4000 nid=0x6303 waiting for monitor entry [0x000070000b47e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at so.T$A.f(T.java:16)
    - waiting to lock <0x0000000718cf6698> (a so.T$A)
    at so.T$A.f(T.java:18)
    - locked <0x0000000718cf66a8> (a so.T$A)
    at so.T.lockInOrder(T.java:25)
    at so.T.lambda$1(T.java:41)
    at so.T$$Lambda$253/103536485.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"Thread-1" #20 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fe885a26000 nid=0x9a03 waiting for monitor entry [0x000070000b37b000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at so.T$A.f(T.java:16)
    - waiting to lock <0x0000000718cf66a8> (a so.T$A)
    at so.T$A.f(T.java:18)
    - locked <0x0000000718cf6698> (a so.T$A)
    at so.T.lockInOrder(T.java:25)
    at so.T.lambda$0(T.java:38)
    at so.T$$Lambda$252/572191680.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Они могут и друг друга захватить и ждать друг друга :)